# search query and showing the results in a jtable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I would like to execute a search query and show the results in a `JTable`. I have a `JComboBox` where the user can choose the field to search in, such as *name*, *age*, or *ID*.

This is my code.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?" + "user=root&password=";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    Statement state = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM db.atelier where '" + 
        jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + "'='" +
        jTextField1.getText().toString() + "'");

    ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();

    while(result.next()){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{result.getObject(1),result.getObject(2)});      
        model.setDataVector(
            new Object[][]{{result.getObject(1),result.getObject(2)},{}},                           
            new Object[]{resultMeta.getColumnName(1),resultMeta.getColumnName(2)});
        }

    jPanel1.revalidate();
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    this.repaint();
    state.close();
}
catch (SQLException e){
    System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException cE){
    System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
}

con=null;
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/230513) concerning SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes around the combobox's selected item should be removed, to make them field names  instead of string literals. Furthermore a PreparedStatement, where the text field is given as an additional parameter replacing `?` in the SQL string is better. That escapes single quotes entered in the text field (and backslashes and so on).

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the way you're building your search query will just expose your application to SQL injection.